# Open a dock type window with x11 and capture key press

Tags: c, x11, xlib

I would like to open a "dock type" window without its title bar with x11 in C and I want to capture a key press (`Ctrl-q`) to close it. The actual code does not capture the key presses to the active window as they are all sent and printed in the terminal. Almost all the `Ctrl` key presses are somehow not detected. The only key presses that actually work on the opened window are `Ctrl-c`. I am aware of the `_MOTIF_WM_HINTS` property but it has the disadvantage to display a window icon in the panel to show a new opened window.

How can I have a "dock type" window while not losing the ability to detect key presses to the active window?

Here is the code basically copied from two other posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31361859/simple-window-without-titlebar) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43113891/handle-c-q-with-xlookupstring)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>
#include <X11/keysym.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(0);

    int blackColor = BlackPixel(dpy, DefaultScreen(dpy));
    int whiteColor = WhitePixel(dpy, DefaultScreen(dpy));

    Window w = XCreateSimpleWindow(dpy, DefaultRootWindow(dpy), 0, 0, 
                     200, 100, 0, blackColor, blackColor);

    //Tell X Server to send MapNotify events
    XSelectInput(dpy, w, StructureNotifyMask | KeyPressMask);
    Atom window_type = XInternAtom(dpy, "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE", False);
    long value = XInternAtom(dpy, "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DOCK", False);

    XChangeProperty(dpy, w, window_type, 4, 32,
                    PropModeReplace,
                    (unsigned char *)&value, 1);

    //Make window appear
    XMapWindow(dpy, w);
    //Graphics Context
    GC gc = XCreateGC(dpy, w, 0, 0);
    //Set white color for drawing
    XSetForeground(dpy, gc, whiteColor);

    //Wait for the MapNotify event
    for(;;) {
        XEvent e;
        XNextEvent(dpy, &e);
        if (e.type == MapNotify) {
          break;
        }
    }

    //Draw the line
    XDrawLine(dpy, w, gc, 10, 60, 180, 20);
    //Send the "DrawLine" request to the server
    XFlush(dpy);

    char text[255];
    XEvent e;
    KeySym key;
    int numKeys = 0;
    for(;;) {
        XNextEvent(dpy, &e);
        if(e.type == KeyPress) {
            if((numKeys = XLookupString(&e.xkey, text, 255, &key, 0))) {
                if(e.xkey.state == ControlMask && key == XK_q) {
                    printf("CTRL-Q\n");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (dpy && gc) XFreeGC(dpy, gc);
    if (dpy && w) XDestroyWindow(dpy, w);
    if (dpy) XCloseDisplay(dpy);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with:
`gcc main.c -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11 -lm && ./a.out`

I've also looked at the `_NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL` property but I haven't been succesful at implementing it.